# Do non-human primates have mental disorders like humans?

Tags: neuroscience, ethology, behaviour, neurology, anthropology

I was at the zoo today and watched a gorilla pick at a scab on its finger, compulsively, until it started bleeding. Is this OCD or is it just a nervous thing that non-human primates do at the zoo? Do gorillas share any of the same mental disorders that humans have?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What attempts have you made to answer this question? We ask that all question posters show an attempt to search for an answer to their own question, show what they learned, and why iit s still confusing/unknown to them. (Studies exist on this subject.) Our goal is not to just be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail and it will likely be received more positively by out community. Thanks!